# Sublime for python's Ctrl+Space function?

Tags: python-2.7, methods, sublimetext3

I have been using sublime-text to write my python codes, but have just realized there is a very useful Ctrl+Space command we can use in the default python IDLE, which makes me re-consider where to write the code again.

Is there any way sublime can do this? Or is there any other text editor that does it?

Comment: Do you mean the autocomplete for names in the current scope? Virtually every decent IDE does that, *including* Sublime - see https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html

Comment: No, I mean, when you press Ctrl+Space after you type 'print 'string'.', it will bring up a drop-down list of all the methods available with a corresponding data type (in this case, string type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`Anaconda`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Anaconda) plugin for ST3 (not related to the Anaconda Python distribution at all). It does a whole bunch of stuff, including intelligent autocomplete based on an object's type, as well as autocompleting methods of imported modules, along with other functions like linting, showing documentation, finding usage of an object, etc. It only works with Python, but really, what other languages are worth programming in? :)

Setup is [pretty straightforward](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/), and allows for you to have different configurations (and different Python interpreters, even virtualenvs) on a per-project basis. I've been using this plugin for quite a while, and I absolutely love it. It's much faster and more accurate than SublimeCodeIntel, and combines functions of several other plugins all in one place.

Comment: Is it just me, or does Anaconda adds many white rectangular boxes around my python code lines? It's very distracting.

Comment: @KubiK888 this can be disabled in the settings. Go to **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Anaconda -> Settings-Default`** and copy the entire contents of the file to **`...-> Anaconda -> Settings-User`**. You can now play around with the settings and see what the issue is. I'm guessing the linter is highlighting potential errors - you can turn this off by setting `"anaconda_linting": false`.